# Average Case Analysis for finding max in array with duplicated element

Tags: runtime-analysis

I've read some posts about counting the number of assignment inside code of finding the maximum value in array like this:

```
FindMax(L):
   n = len(L)
   max = L[1]
   for i = 2..n:
      if (max < L[i]) 
          max = L[i] (**)
   return max
```

According to this [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89842/average-case-analysis-for-finding-max-and-min-value-on-an-array) and [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55786/average-case-analysis-of-a-simple-max-finding-algorithm), it's about the array that elements are strictly distinguish. So if the array contains values may be duplicated *(for example, elements are integer in range [1, m], m = 3, with any length of array)*, how could we calculate the number of (**) will be executed in average case?

Comment: Average case is with respect to an input distribution. Which input distribution do you have in mind? Each element is chosen independently and uniformly at random from $1,\dots,m$, for some constant $m$?

Comment: Use linearity of expectation and indicator variables. All you need to know is the probability that element $i$ is larger than all previous elements.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes, it is.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus So could you please explain it more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the following distribution: each array element is chosen independently and uniformly from $\{1,\ldots,m\}$. Let us denote by $I_i$ the indicator variable for the event that ( ** ) gets executed for the $i$th element (so $I_i = 1$ if ( ** ) gets executed, and $I_i = 0$ otherwise). Linearity of expectation shows that the expected number of times that (**) gets executed is $$ \sum_{i=2}^n \Pr[I_i]. $$
(This uses the fact that $\mathbb{E}[I_i] = \Pr[I_i]$.)

It remains to compute the probability of $I_i$. If $A[i] = j$ then (**) happens iff $A[1],\ldots,A[i-1] \in \{1,\ldots,j-1\}$, which happens with probability $\bigl(\tfrac{j-1}{m}\bigr)^{i-1}$. Therefore
$$
\Pr[I_i] = \sum_{j=2}^m \frac{1}{m} \left(\frac{j-1}{m}\right)^{i-1}.
$$
In total, we get
$$
\sum_{i=2}^n \Pr[I_i] = \sum_{j=2}^m \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=2}^n \left(\frac{j-1}{m}\right)^{i-1}.
$$
You take it from here.

Comment: +1 for this excellent explaination :D btw it is the mean of number of times, so are there any way for me to calculate the variance?

Comment: The same approach works for other moments as well, though the calculations are more difficult. You have to calculate the probability of both events $I_i$ and $I_j$ occurring simultaneously.

Comment: I've got it after a little time of thinking. Btw after some step of calculating, I couldn't get the formula that only depends on n & m. I only could get the following: [1 - (k/m)^(n-1)] / (m - k), for k = 1..m-1. So are there anyway to continue?

Comment: Sometimes getting a nice exact expression is too much to ask for, and instead we are interested in sharp asymptotic estimates.